# how to transition opacity to show another div?

Tags: css

I created div with class **.overlayFeatured** and has an opacity **0** I want to transition the opacity to **1** when I hover over the parent div which has the class **.imageOdd** So here is my css code:

```
         .overlayFeatured{
               position: absolute;
               height: 100%;
               width: 100%;
               background: rgba(0,143,161,0.2);
               opacity: 0;
                         }
          .imageOdd{
               height: 248px;
               box-shadow: 0px 15px 30px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
               position: relative;
               transition: opacity 5s linear;
               &:hover{
                  cursor: pointer;
                  transition: opacity 5s linear;
                  .overlayFeatured{
                          opacity: 1;
                          .likes{
                               opacity: 1;
                                }
                                  }
                                        }
                                       }
```

and here is the html code :

```
          <div class="imageOdd mb-3">
              <div class="overlayFeatured">
                  <section class="likes">
                      <div class="cart" 
                       @click="addCart(`<?php echo $featured['name'];?>`)" >
                            <i class="fa fa-book" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
                       </div>
                       <div class="like">
                           <i class="fa fa-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                       </div>
                        </section>
                        </div>
                        <img 
                         src="public/images/<?php echo $featured['image'];?
                         >" alt="" class="img-fluid imageFeatured">
                    </div>
```

Comment: what is your css preprocessor? Less or Sass

Comment: First. This is not CSS. Looks like SCSS or LESS. ( CSS preprocessors ). Second, where is the HTML ?

Comment: I added the html code and yes this is scss

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transition is at the wrong place:

```
.overlayFeatured{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,143,161,0.2);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 5s linear; //<-- transition must be here
}
.imageOdd{
  height: 248px;
  box-shadow: 0px 15px 30px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
  position: relative;
  &:hover{
    cursor: pointer;
    .overlayFeatured{
      opacity: 1;
      .likes{
        opacity: 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

According to the CSS documentation: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp it's the start element which have the configuration of the transition.

When the value of the transition's property changes, the transition is triggered

Comment: why is it in the wrong place ? You should include some explanation in the answer.

Comment: @MihaiT I add, the documentation link

Answer (score 0):

Your transition isn't working because the `.overlayFeatured` doesn't know that it has to transition, so it just pops the opacity to 1 instantly.

In your SCSS (assuming it's SCSS) you have the transition on the `&:hover` AND on the `.imageOdd` which are both redundant. The transition should be placed on the `.overlayFeatured` like so:

**SCSS**

```
.overlayFeatured {
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background: rgba(0, 143, 161, 0.2);
        opacity: 0;

        transition: opacity 5s linear; //<======= transition here
}
.imageOdd {
        height: 248px;
        box-shadow: 0px 15px 30px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        position: relative;
        &:hover {
            cursor: pointer;
            .overlayFeatured {
                opacity: 1;
                .likes {
                    opacity: 1;
                }
         }
    }
}
```

**Example (Set as CSS for I am not sure if it supports SCSS, the SCSS is found above)**

```css
.overlayFeatured {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 143, 161, 0.2);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 5s linear;
}

.imageOdd {
  height: 248px;
  box-shadow: 0px 15px 30px -10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  position: relative;
}
.imageOdd:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.imageOdd:hover .overlayFeatured {
  opacity: 1;
}
.imageOdd:hover .overlayFeatured .likes {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="imageOdd">
  <div class="overlayFeatured"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!